# Problems scaling map. Shiny + leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I can't have "full screen" map in my shiny app, because when I used "100%" parameter, the map disappears...

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap", height = "100%", width = "100%"),
```

But when I do this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
```

there is no problems, but there is a half with map and a half in blank. And I need it to be full screen

I tried

```
leafletOutput("mymap", height = 800, width = 1300)
```

But it is not what I need, because it didn't scale to the window, that's why I prefer the "100%" parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I guess with 100% height you mean "fit to screen/window"?

```
jscode <- '
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
var jsHeight = window.innerHeight;
Shiny.onInputChange("GetScreenHeight",jsHeight);
});
'


library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  p(),
  tags$script(jscode),
  uiOutput("leafl"),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })

  output$leafl <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$GetScreenHeight)){
      width  <- session$clientData$output_image1_width
      print(session$clientData)
      height <- session$clientData$output_image1_height
      leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100%", height = input$GetScreenHeight)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```